# create directory structure from tree command output

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I have few `tree` command output of some directory structures (in text files). It looks something like:

```
% cat tree.txt
.
├── grandpartest
│   └── partest
│       └── test
│           ├── empty-asciidoc-document.adoc
│           └── empty-asciidoc-document1.adoc
├── grandpartest2
│   └── partest2
│       └── test2
│           ├── empty-asciidoc-document.adoc
│           ├── empty-asciidoc-document1.adoc
│           └── empty-asciidoc-document2.adoc
├── grandpartest3
│   └── partest3
│       └── test3
│           ├── empty-asciidoc-document.adoc
│           ├── empty-asciidoc-document1.adoc
│           ├── empty-asciidoc-document2.adoc
│           └── empty-asciidoc-document3.adoc
└── tree.txt

9 directories, 10 files
```

Is there any way I can parse these text files to create similar directory structure?

I know I can use `mkdir -p` and `touch` to create this directory structure. But the main thing I am interested in is to parse the text file to get the values to use with these commands.

**Update 1:**

As per the request of @muru

```
% cat tree-j.txt
[{"type":"directory","name": ".","contents":[
    {"type":"directory","name":"grandpartest","contents":[
      {"type":"directory","name":"partest","contents":[
        {"type":"directory","name":"test","contents":[
          {"type":"file","name":"empty-asciidoc-document.adoc"},
          {"type":"file","name":"empty-asciidoc-document1.adoc"}
        ]}
      ]}
    ]},
    {"type":"directory","name":"grandpartest2","contents":[
      {"type":"directory","name":"partest2","contents":[
        {"type":"directory","name":"test2","contents":[
          {"type":"file","name":"empty-asciidoc-document.adoc"},
          {"type":"file","name":"empty-asciidoc-document1.adoc"},
          {"type":"file","name":"empty-asciidoc-document2.adoc"},
          {"type":"directory","name":"Untitled Folder","contents":[
          ]}
        ]}
      ]}
    ]},
    {"type":"directory","name":"grandpartest3","contents":[
      {"type":"directory","name":"partest3","contents":[
        {"type":"directory","name":"test3","contents":[
          {"type":"file","name":"empty-asciidoc-document.adoc"},
          {"type":"file","name":"empty-asciidoc-document1.adoc"},
          {"type":"file","name":"empty-asciidoc-document2.adoc"},
          {"type":"file","name":"empty-asciidoc-document3.adoc"}
        ]}
      ]}
    ]},
    {"type":"file","name":"tree.txt"},
    {"type":"file","name":"tree-j.txt"}
  ]},
  {"type":"report","directories":10,"files":11}
]

% cat tree-j.txt | parse-tree
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/blueray/_resources/dotfiles/python/parse-tree", line 18, in <module>
    process(structure)
  File "/home/blueray/_resources/dotfiles/python/parse-tree", line 10, in process
    os.mkdir(entry["name"])
FileExistsError: [Errno 17] File exists: '.'
```

Comment: And you can't get the original structures to run commands that could provide more easily parsed output?

Comment: AIUI, you you use `tree` because you want to edit output to alter the directory structure, but other, more parseable, outputs could also be edited to alter the structure, probably just as easily.

Comment: From tree output, how would you know if it's e.g `empty-asciidoc-document.adoc` is not a directory? In your text file it is not colored anymore.

Comment: @blueray for example, use `tree -J` to get JSON output. Then that can be processed with a script like https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/TGvYyCfqhW/ (which handles the simple case of only directories and files).

Comment: @blueray that error I'd like to see, and the `tree-j.txt` file as well.

Comment: use `os.makedirs(entry["name"], exist_ok=True)` instead of `os.mkdir(entry["name"])`. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600268/mkdir-p-functionality-in-python

Comment: ask @muru to write an answer ;-)

Comment: @muru please write an answer so that I can accept.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Parsing the usual output of `tree` is tricky - it's not some standard form like, say, a CSV. Standard, structured formats like JSON would be better, since you'd need to encode at least two or three pieces of information per entry (name, type, and additional information like link targets or directory entries that would vary according to file type). `tree -J` does provide pretty simple JSON output, and you can use Python, which is part of default Ubuntu installations and has JSON processing in the standard library, to process it:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

import json
import os
import sys

def process(entries):
    for entry in entries:
        if entry["type"] == "directory":
            os.makedirs(entry["name"], exist_ok=True) # Thanks @pLumo
            os.chdir(entry["name"])
            process(entry.get("contents", []))
            os.chdir('..')
        if entry["type"] == "file":
            with open(entry["name"], "w"): pass
        if entry["type"] == "link":
            os.symlink(entry["name"], entry["target"])

# read standard input
structure = json.load(sys.stdin)
process(structure)
```

This only handles directories, regular files and links; you'll need to add conditions for other file types (not sure how `tree` handles block devices, character devices, etc.).